# Why Flutter statefull widget didn't change the state of another statefull widget when I call it inside its widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have created two `Stateful Widget` classes name **`Editor{}`** that contains the Employee card UI and the **`RPMSlider()`** that controls the Radius of Items in a card.

I call the `RPMSlider()` in  `Editor Widget` which looks like this in the below image,

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gvrc.png)

My question is when I Adjust the slider it perfectly works and shows the value above it.

But it cannot make a change in the meantime in a Card UI. Until I click a **`button`** or **`gesturedetector`** having **`SetState();`**

> Slider function works fine when it is created inside **`Editor()`** but in a separate Stateful widget it cannot make changes in Card

Here is The
[Gif Show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftLE8.gif)

This is an Editor

```
class Editor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EditorState createState() => _EditorState();
}
class _EditorState extends State<Editor> {
  double size = 1;
  var width, height;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    // print(width* 0.5733);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            //TODO: Left Side
            Container(
              width: width * 0.300,
              color: Color(0xffdbe5e7),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  //Permanent Area
                ],
              ),
            ),

            Container(
              height: height,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              width: width * 0.400,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffdbe5e7),
              ),
              //TODO: Card Area

              child: FlipCard(
                key: cardKey,
                flipOnTouch: false,
                ///EDITABLE CARD FRONT
                front: Container(),
                ///EDITABLE CARD Back
                back: Container(),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: width * 0.300,
              color: Color(0xffdbe5e7),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  //TODO: Radius , Padding , Margins
                  RPMSlider(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is RPMSlider**

```
 class RPMSlider extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _RPMSliderState createState() => _RPMSliderState();

}

class _RPMSliderState extends State<RPMSlider> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return radius(caseId: widgetIdCarrier,);

  }

 radius({required String caseId,label='label',position='topLeft'}) {
   return Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
     child: Column(
       children: [
         Row(
           children: [
             Text(
               label.toUpperCase(),
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black54),
             ),
             Spacer(),
             Text(
               radiusValue.round().toString(),
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.black54),
             ),
           ],
         ),
         SizedBox(
           height: 4,
         ),
         NeumorphicSlider(
           min: 0.0,
           max: 30,
           sliderHeight: 30,
           thumb: NeumorphicIcon(
             Icons.circle,
             size: 20,
           ),
           height: 1,
           style: SliderStyle(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
               lightSource: LightSource.bottomRight),
           value:radiusValue

           onChanged: (sts) {
             setState(() {
               radiusValue=sts;
             });
            
           },
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
}


}
```

Comment: That is a *ton* of code. Maybe you can break that down into a [mcve]?

Comment: Code has been broken in minimal reproducible, Thank You

Comment: you should see the GIF image. to see the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the slider cannot change another widget. It can only change it self. It can also provide callbacks when it *has* changed. Other widgets already do that, like the `NeumorphicSlider` that you use has an `onChanged` callback that it calls when something has changed so you can make adjustments outside the widget.

So give your widget an `onChanged` callback, too:

```
class RPMSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<int>? onChanged;

  RPMSlider({this.onChanged});
```

Now in your state class, whenever you get notified that the value has changed, you notify others that is has changed:

```
  onChanged: (sts) {
     setState(() {
       radiusValue = sts;
     });
     // the new part:
     final callBack = widget.onChanged
     if(callBack != null) {
        callBack(sts);
     }
```

Now in your EditorState, you can use it like this:

```
RPMSlider(onChanged: (value) {
     setState(() {
       your_state_variable = value; 
       // don't know what your_state_variable is,
       // you need to pick the one you need for this
     });
})
```

So now, the `setState` method is called inside the correct state class, that can actually change both widgets, the slider and the other one.